# Why Django does not check email integrity when creating a new user?

Tags: django, tastypie

I don't understand this behaviour. Let's say I open a Django shell and type:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.create(username="toto", email="titi")
```

Why does Django let me create this user (with an invalid email) without raising an error?

I have the same "no verification behaviour" creating a user in a POST in my API created with tastypie.

The question is:

As Django does not seem to check this by itself, where am I supposed to perform this kind of verifications sothat I don't have to write them several times (since a user can be created in several ways like website, API, etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django doesn't implicitly do any validation if you just call `.create()` or `.save()` - you need to explicitly use [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), or save the object via a 
[`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). Your example with model validation would look like this:

```
user = User(username="toto", email="titi")
try:
    user.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # handle the error...
    pass
user.save()
```

Or using a `ModelForm`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

f = UserForm(dict(username="toto", email="titi"))
if f.is_valid():
    user = f.save()
else:
    # handle error, ...
    pass
```

Both model validation and `ModelForm`s invoke the model field's validators, so in the case of the `User`'s email, no additional work is needed for validation. If you need to do custom validation, [you can do this in the `ModelForm` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) - it is common to have a `forms.py` file in the app as a central place for `Form`s and `ModelForm`s.

The same goes for Tastypie - the default configuration assumes the data submitted is valid. You can override this with the [`FormValidation`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#formvalidation) class, which uses a Django `Form` or `ModelForm` for its validation. A full example would look something like this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=UserForm)  # UserForm from above
        # more options here....
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this perfect answer! This makes sens. My forms.py contains Forms only (not ModelForms (but not sure to entirely understand differences between them)). But if I follow what you told me, I just have to ensure that all the validors are well set in my forms.py, and then "plugging" the validation in tastypie. This way, validators are written one time, but they're called both in my django website AND with POST request in my API. That's very elegant! Thanks again.

Comment: Nice explanation of difference between forms and modelform : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303268/djangos-forms-form-vs-forms-modelform
I <3 StackOverflow :)