# Cannot update user profile information

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to create a form that would allow a user to edit some of the information saved in their profile.

The problem I am having currently is that when a user fills in the form and saves it, the information in their profile is not updated based on the values they filled in.

I have tried reading through the documentation on forms in Django but still struggling to figure this out.

This is the code i have in forms.py:

```
#mentor sign up form
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user


# edit mentor profile
class MentorProfileForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta(TeacherSignUpForm.Meta):
        model = User
        exclude = ('password')
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Mentor.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        post_save.connect(create_or_update, sender=User)
```

teachers.py - this is the equivalent of views.py - specific to the mentor/teacher profile:

```
# edit mentor profile
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    form = MentorProfileForm(initial={'first_name': user.first_name, 'last_name': user.last_name, 'email': user.email})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = MentorProfileForm(request.POST['first_name'])
            user.last_name = MentorProfileForm(request.POST['last_name'])
            user.email = MentorProfileForm(request.POST['email'])
            # user.password = request.POST['password']
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('profile')))
        else:
            form = MentorProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form})
```

this is the template I am using with the form

```
<form id="edit-mentor-profile" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media v-middle">
                            <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="icon-block width-100 bg-grey-100">
                                <i class="fa fa-photo text-light"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-sm paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated> Add Image<i class="fa fa-upl"></i></a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                {{ form.first_name }}
                                <label for="edit-mentor-profile-first_name"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                {{ form.last_name }}
                                <label for="edit-mentor-profile-last_name"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                              {{ form.email }}
                              <label for="edit-mentor-profile-email"></label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                            <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked="">
                            <label for="checkbox3">Subscribe to our Newsletter</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group margin-none">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated>Save Changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

To reiterate I can view the form, edit it but when I try and save the values, nothing is saved and the page refreshes

**Update**

After reading about ModelForm I have tried to make some changes to my forms.py to the best of my ability

forms.py

```
class MentorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('password',)
```

Based on one of the answers given I also made changes to  models.py

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        post_save.connect(create_or_update, sender=User)
```

and teachers.py (views):

```
# edit mentor profile
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    form = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MentorProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            # user.password = request.POST['password']
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('profile')))
        else:
            return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form,
                                                                                      'errors': form.errors})
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You need to pass instance=object when updating your objects via model forms

Comment: @IainShelvington mind elaborating please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the issue is here:

```
class MentorProfileForm(forms.Form):  #<-- Here
    class Meta(TeacherSignUpForm.Meta):
        model = User
        exclude = ('password')
```

There is no save function for `forms.Form`, for that you need to subclass `MentorProfileForm` from `forms.ModelForm`. Or in your case, `TeacherSignUpForm`(as you are overriding it's Meta class).

Also, I am confused about this part as well:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
      ....
      # this section
      mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
      )
      return user
```

Because, you have a post save signal to create Mentor, then why are you using it? Better if you remove the post save signal and use get_or_create here, ie:

```
  _, mentor = Mentor.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        linkedin=self.cleaned_data.get('linkedin')
  )
```

Finally, update the view as well:

```
form = MentorProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. A little confused about the first part (no save function for forms.Form)

Comment: Probably you should look into the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form. Also this post will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303268/djangos-forms-form-vs-forms-modelform. Basically, when you subclass from `forms.Form`, it does not provide any save functionality, but if you use `forms.ModelForm`, then it will allow you to generate forms from Model and save them in DB when you invoke `form_instance.save()`

Comment: I am updated my question with what I tried based on what I understood

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the "instance" when you update any model instance. Change your view to this:

```py
# edit mentor profile
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    form = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            # user.password = request.POST['password']
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('profile')))
        else:
            return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form, 'errors': form.errors})
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: getting the error message: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: `MentorProfileForm` should inherit from `forms.ModelForm`.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have tried based on the answers given

Comment: are you getting any error? try to print form.errors in your template.

Comment: got it to work with a combination of you answer and ruddra's. Thanks