# Django - How to make a notification?f when User Register It will send notification to Email of Admin

Tags: python, django, web

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Username',
                })
            )
    email = forms.EmailField(
            max_length=200,
            widget=forms.TextInput({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Email'
                })
            )
    password = forms.CharField(
            min_length=6, max_length=10,
            widget=forms.PasswordInput({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Password'
                })
            )

    repeat_password = forms.CharField(
            min_length=6, max_length=10,
            widget=forms.PasswordInput({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Repeat password'
                })
            )
```

Here is my form.py, how to make an email notification to the email of server ? That will notify the admin that there is a new User register to his application.

Answer (score 0):

Django implements `mail_admins()` which is configured by the `ADMINS` setting, as can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#mail-admins).

### Basic Usage

```py
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

mail_admins(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    fail_silently=False
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to use `ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form` See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303268/djangos-forms-form-vs-forms-modelform) to see the difference of `ModelForm` and `Form` on detail.

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
     .....
     class Meta:
        model = YourUserModel
        fields = [...]
```

Now from the view you can send email to the site admin like this after new user account created.

```
 form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       user = form.save()
       # now you can send mail to the site admin
       mail_admins('subject','message')
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#mail-admins) for sending email

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set a [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal on user that will trigger one's user is created:

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def user_created_email_notification(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.id:
         mail_admins('subject','message')
```